# Solving the Recurrence Relation T(n)=T(n-1)*T(n-2)+c where T(0)=1 and T(1)=2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I need to solve the recurrence relation for

```
T(n) = T(n - 1) * T(n - 2) + c    where T(0) = 1 and T(1) = 2.
```

The algorithm computes 2<sup>f(n)</sup> where f(n) is the n<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number. I assume that T(n - 2) is approximately equal to T(n - 1) and then I rewrite the relation as

```
T(n) = T(n - 1)^2 + c
```

and finality I reach to complexity of O(n). This the algorithm:

```
Power(n):
    if n == 0 then x = 1;
    else if n == 1 then x = 2;
    else x = Power(n - 1) * Power(n - 2);
    return x;
```

Is it true that the recurrence relation T(n) = T(n - 1) * T(n - 2) + c has O(n) complexity?

Comment: Your code takes O(2^N) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing multiplication in the algorithm with multiplication in the recurrence relation. You calculate `Power(n - 1)` and `Power(n - 2)` and multiply them, but this does not take `T(n - 1) * T(n - 2)` time. These values are computed separately, and then multiplied, taking `T(n - 1) + T(n - 2)` time, assuming constant-time multiplication.

The recurrence then becomes `T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + c`. We'll solve this by substitution. I'll skip choosing an n<sub>0</sub>; our induction hypothesis will be `T(n) = d * 2^n - 1`. (We need the -1 to allow of to later cancel the `c`; this is called strengthening the induction hypothesis, see e.g. [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2008fa/lectures/lec19.html)).

```
T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) + c
     = d * (2^(n - 1) - 1) + d * (2^(n - 2) - 1) + c    (substitute by IH)
     = 3d * 2^(n - 2) - 2d + c
    <= d * 2^n - 2d + c                                 (3 < 2^2)
    <= d * 2^n                                          (when d > c / 2)
```

Conclusion: T(n) ∈ O(2<sup>n</sup>).

Bonus fact: the tight bound is actually Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>), where φ is the golden ratio. See [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/9908/30997) for an explanation.

Comment: @Jori. Many thanks, you are right I though when there is multiplication in algorithm then the recurrence relation also will be multiplication form. It was my misunderstanding :). So if the  T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c so  it is equal to Fibonacci relation where by considering T(n-2)≈T(n-1) we obtain the upper bound as  Ω(2^n) and when we consider T(n-1)≈T(n-2) we obtain the lower bound as θ(2^(n/2)). Am I right? ;)

Comment: @HesamE, no, for two constants, C,D>1 we have that O(C^n) = O(D^n), simply because `C = D^{log_D C}` and so `C^n` = D^{n * log_D C}`. But the limit of C^n / D^{n* log_D C} goes to infinity as n goes to infinity.

Comment: In particular, 2^n grows asymptotically *faster* than `g^n` where by `g` I denote the golden ratio.

Answer (score 1):

First, the recurrence that models the running time is `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + C` for `T(1) = T(0) = 1`, for some `C>0`. This is because you make two recursive calls, one on `n-1` and the other on `n-2`.

The recurrence you have is precisely the [Fibonacci recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) if we forget the additional constant (which contributed a factor `C` in the end). The exact solution is this (image source: Wikipedia):

[image]

where

[image]

and

[image]

You could say that `T(n) = Theta(1.618... ^ n)`.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Also I put one comment below the next solution by "Jordi", could you please review it. Thanks ;)